# House With Even Doors

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a house (with finitely many rooms) in which every room has an even number of doors. Prove that the number of doors from the house to the outside world is also even.

I don't get this problem, what is it asking for?  I would like an answer not involving graph theory, since this was one of my homework questions in a counting and probability course.

Comment: Hint:  consider a door connecting two rooms.  In the total count, it appears twice (once for each room).

Answer (score 3):

This question does not require combinatorics at all. It is a graph-theoretical question, if each room is a vertex and each door an edge.

> A graph cannot have exactly one vertex of odd degree.

And it follows from the hand-shaking lemma, which stipulates that the sum of all vertices' degrees in a graph must be even; the outside world is considered a vertex, and only by making its degree even (number of doors to outside is even) can the lemma be satisfied.

Comment: Many would consider graph theory part of combinatorics, so the tag is appropriate.